# CSS: Progress Bar + asp:Label inside it

Tags: asp.net, css

I have the Progress bar div and the asp:label inside it. How to style it to have that Label inside it and in the middle of that div ?

```
<div id="progressbar" style="width: 350px;">
    <asp:Label ID="percentLabel" runat="server" Text="0" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way (*if you use it as inline*) is to set `text-align:center` on the div.

Alternatively, if you want to use it as a block element, you should set the following properties on the label `display:block`, `width: XXpx` (*where XX < than 350px*) and `margin:0px auto` which means have equal distance from the sides, thus centered..